# Riddle quatrain: A paper pound of wrong and round

Tags: riddle

> A paper pound of wrong and round,
>   A minty piggy named.
>   Dividing nine, some yours, some mine,
>   A syzygy is claimed.

---

To start off the new year, my first riddle! I'd really appreciate feedback. Thanks to everyone who gave advice on [riddle-writing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5249/4551) and [rhyming](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105/4551)-- it was very helpful.

I tried to make every phrase have a precise interpretation connected to the answer.

Comment: a tic-tac-toe game?

Comment: @duhaime I really think that is the correct solution. Why don't you delete the comment and write a proper answer?

Comment: +1 for the minty piggy. That took me a minute to figure out even after knowing the answer :D

Comment: I love the minty piggy!

Comment: @xnor: I really liked this - although I'm not a big fan of riddles. The best was, that Googling "syzygy" only gave me a German company of that name...

Comment: @xnor: You should have posted 17hrs and 4mins earlier. I would have voted it my [top-2014 puzzle](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/best-puzzles-of-2014) ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest Wow, thanks! There's always 2015...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is quite simple

> *The end result* of a **tic tac toe** (or **Xs and Os**, **Noughts/Knaughts and Crosses**, etc. See; http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#English_names) game.

*Why?*

**A paper pound of wrong and round,**

> The game is played on paper with Xs (wrong) and Os (round). Pound having to do with **#** which is the shape of a tic tac toe **board**.

**A minty piggy named.**

> A **tic tac** is minty. Then there's piggy **toe**!

**Dividing nine, some yours, some mine,**

> The game is split us into **9 slots**. Some slots are **owned** by **you**, **some** by your **friend**, Xs and Os!

**A syzygy is claimed.**

> In astronomy a syzygy is the alignment of **3** celestial bodies! In other words, **3 in a row is achieved**, or a *"tic-tac-toe"* Win!

*One **note** [**POSSIBLE SPOILER**];

> *Games can end in **ties**, so the last line is **arguably correct**.*

Comment: I can't figure out #2 though...

Comment: Minty=[tic-tac](http://www.tictacusa.com/en/), piggy=[toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Little_Piggy) ;)

Comment: You left out the meaning of "pound", as in the character "#".

Comment: This is all completely right! I'm accepting this because even though duhaime answered earlier, he hasn't come back to explain his answer.

Comment: @xnor Yea, I noticed it's all ... (Which is why **I** answered.) thanks for the +15 (or if you upvoted, +25, I think?)

Comment: @xnor Made the answers slight clearer and added a name to the list in answer. With source, source including 1 or 2 more.