# What Guy Am I, Am I Sonic?

Tags: riddle

I could be a bolt

I will meet you at the 100m before the world could catch me

Ask me using my name,

I will say "Yes"

I love yellow and green and my lightning-hot nickname

Who am I?

Hint:

> I am not Sonic the Hedgehog

No more hints as the clues can be deciphered without any more help. Good Luck!

Comment: Too easy! Answered within 4 min - well done Pac.

Comment: I will never make good riddles

Comment: if you change the color from green to red you get a whole new (relatively easy) answer

Comment: @PythonMaster Don't give up too soon! :-) You just need to obfuscate the clues a bit more. There are some good posts here about how to write a good riddle: [one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/how-do-i-write-a-solid-riddle), [two](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-you-come-up-with-a-good-classic-rhyme-riddle), [three](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/tips-for-solving-poem-riddles)

Comment: I'm not giving up. The fact people answer so fast is a riddle to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Usain Bolt

I could be a bolt

> Bolt is your last name.

I will meet you at the 100m before the world could catch me

> You own the world record in the 100 meter dash.

Ask me using my name,

> If I ask you "Usain" as in "You sane?"

I will say "Yes"

> Presumably you will say you are sane.

I love yellow and green and my lightning-hot nickname

> Jamaica's colors are yellow and green, and your nickname is "Lightning Bolt".