# The lamest rhyme I ever wrote

Tags: riddle, language

> The lamest rhyme I ever wrote
>   Was one involving Don Quixote.
>   No, wait, a lamer one than that,
>   The famous movie Chocolat.
>   But maybe even lamer still,
>   The butchering of "centre-ville".
>   And finally, to fill this hole,
>   The food we know as ____________.

What word ends this horrible rhyming stanza?

Comment: I was cringing the whole time reading this. But seeing the answer, all is forgiven. :) Nicely done.

Comment: @JoeZ. massively late to the party, but "still" *does* rhyme with "centre-ville" ?

Comment: "centre-ville" isn't a word in English. If you pronounce it in the English way, yes it rhymes with "still", but nobody actually pronounces it that way.

Comment: well if you say centre-ville in quebec french, yes it does rhyme. :P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word is

> guacamole

Reasoning:

> The pairs of words all look like they rhyme since they end in pretty much the same letters, but they don't actually rhyme.
>
> "wrote" doesn't rhyme with "Quixote", which is pronounced in the Spanish way.
>
> "that" doesn't rhyme with the French pronunciation of "chocolat"
>
> "still" doesn't rhyme with the French pronunciation of "centre-ville"
>
> "hole" doesn't rhyme with "guacamole", which is pronounced in the Spanish way.
>
> They're all lame rhymes since none of them actually rhyme!

Comment: Perfect! Everything is correct.

Comment: Also a note: Quixote and guacamole are both Spanish words.

Comment: Nuts you beat me to it.