# Rhythmic riddle poem

Tags: riddle, letters

> This poem has a symbol, and the symbol is a pea;
>   It goes all through a tunnel, and the tunnel is a hole.
>   Now the poem is so eerie, and it's slipping in an eel.
>   "Hem-hem," said Mrs Umbridge, with a long and speedy dash.

---

The riddle itself is quite easy, but I had fun writing it as a poem with a nice rollicking rhythm.

Comment: The fact that none of the couplets rhyme is irritating me unreasonably much.

Comment: @JoeZ. And all the time I spent getting the rhythm right... What does it take to satisfy some people? :-P

Comment: I mean, [I probably shouldn't be complaining](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11868/88), but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's

> POEM

Here is why

> all lines reference a letter

This poem has a symbol, and the symbol is a pea;

> reference the letter P in a phonetic way
>  Pea sounds like P.

It goes all through a tunnel, and the tunnel is a hole.

> reference the letter O in a visual way
>  O looks like a hole or the end of the tunnel

Now the poem is so eerie, and it's slipping in an eel.

> As mentioned by *Mark N*
>  E is the letter inside e**e**l (it's slipping in it)

"Hem-hem," said Mrs Umbridge, with a long and speedy dash.

> Hem-Hem = M
>  There is 2 common versions of dash, the short one or en dash and the long one or em dash

Comment: +1, but can you explain the "eerie" and "dash" parts?

Comment: @randal'thor I have to find the "eerie" part. I think I have the "dash" part

Comment: The dash part is simpler than that! Also, Hole = O isn't really "phonetic"...

Comment: slipping 'in' and eel..e'e'l..?

Comment: @randal'thor I updated my answer. Still have no clue for the dash

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with Professor Umbridge from Harry Potter? She says "hem hem" whenever she wants to interrupt someone...

Comment: @randal'thor I updated my answer, but I run out of solutions :)

Comment: What do you call a long dash? Also "slipping" could be seen as a reference to the double E: if your finger slips on the E key, you might get two E's instead of one. @KritixiLithos Indeed, that's who I'm referring to!

Comment: @randal'thor I got it now. Since English is not my first language, I have a lot to learn on double meanings :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a joke in response to Joe Z's comment about the rhymes.

My alternate (*Fresh prince*) edition for the riddle:

> Now this is a story all about how,
>
> my Eel life got flipped-turned upside down,
>
> and I'd like to take a minute, just sit right there.
>
> I'll tell you how this Eel ate a pea and dashed home to  Bel Air!
> (Bel air is in a hole where Mrs. Umbridge must live.)
>
> Deep down in the water, I was born and raised.
>
> Swimming around was how I spent most of my days.
>
> Chillin' out, snacking relaxing all cool,
>
> Eating some food that fell in the pool.
>
> When Mrs. Umbridge, came over and was up to no good!
>
> Started throwing Peas in my neighborhood.
>
> I ate one little pea, it went straight down my throat hole,
>
> and then Mrs. Umbridge said 'Ee!..hem-hem, that was not my goal.'