# It plants the seed in all

Tags: riddle

> This thing the weak it crushes,
>   Like noxious weed it clutches;
>   The brave that crave it grow,
>   On and on they fall.
>   Workers, learners, thinkers,
>   It plants the seed in all.

Comment: I really like the rhythm of it

Comment: thanks, I tried to follow this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_tetrameter

Comment: Also based it on the first riddle from here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-you-come-up-with-a-good-classic-rhyme-riddle

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. This is a really good first riddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Love

This thing the weak it crushes,

> To those who aren't strong willed, love can crush them if someone leaves/dies. Also crushes as another reference to love

Like noxious weed it clutches;

> It's hard not to feel or stamp out love, and it can be harmful in some situations. Like for the weak mentioned above, it can lead to depression, or the feeling of love lost can continue hurting you long after that person is gone.

The brave that crave it grow,

> If you are brave enough to keep striving for relationships after one ended, you grow as a person as does your capacity for love. You learn to treasure things more, and what is important to you.

On and on they fall.

> Brave people who are willing to risk their hearts will fall in love again and again

Workers, learners, thinkers,

> People of different walks of life love and value different things

It plants the seed in all.

> Everyone has the capacity to love

Comment: Really nice guess. +1

Answer (score 2):

It's

> Doubt

This thing the weak it crushes,

> If you don't have a strong belief, doubt will crush you

Like noxious weed it clutches;

> You can't get rid of it easily

The brave that crave it grow,

> Only by cultivating doubt one can really grow, but it requires more courage than holding blindly to a belief

On and on they fall.

> I think it refers to the false beliefs that fall when inspected with doubt

Workers, learners, thinkers,
It plants the seed in all.

> The seed of doubt, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be

> HOPE

As,

> Hopelessness crushes the weak
>  Hope is an ever-powerful inspiration for anyone to live
>  Brave can pursue their hopes even after many hurdles/ stumbling
>  Across all kinds of walks of life people would require of hope(which was seeded earlier) to continue their lives!

Comment: Nice one. +1 :)